# Resolving Geoserver ERROR: Operation on two geometries with different SRIDs?

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2, postgis, geoserver

I am working on GeoServer Version 2.4.2 . I have one layer 'beat' in PostgreSQL database. I have publish layer in geoserver but its not opening OpenLayers layer preview link. It gives error as

```
Internal error occurred java.io.IOException null ERROR: Operation on two geometries with different SRIDs
```

I have checked all previous question but i didn't understand how to resolve this. I try exporting the layer and it export successfully in shp and render in QGis. Also it export in geojson succesfully so why its not rendering in layer preview i am **confused**. I tried following queries but it shows proper results as

```
select * from geometry_columns where f_table_name = 'beat';
    f_table_catalog  f_table_schema  f_table_name  f_geometry_column  coord_dimension  srid   type          
    ---------------  --------------  ------------  -----------------  ---------------  -----  ------------  
                     nmmccommon      beat          the_geom           2                32643  MULTIPOLYGON 

select distinct(st_srid(the_geom)) from beat;
st_srid  
-------  
32463
```

Distinct srid is also single then at what point Operation on two geometries with different SRIDs  error occure. Geosever can export it shp also successfully render in QGis. I know its repitative question but i didn't found a useful solution which suits in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by setting srid again to beat table.

```
UPDATE beat SET the_geom = ST_SetSRID(the_geom,32643);
```

after that layer render successfully . Actually i don't understand the problem but in my case i am sure about the projection so i reassign the srid.